# IOS shareKit ARC

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, sharekit

Please I downloaded the ShareKit libraries but I have the problem with ARC so I have 400 errors from the ARC.

What I have to do to resolve this problem?

Thank you,

Comment: fno-objc-arc for all ShareKit classes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project

Comment: @Injectios can u please help me how can i add the fno-objc-arc for all those classes

Comment: @Houssam look at the link I posted it explains how to do it. There is even a sample project showing you how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ShareKit has been migrated to ARC. Please use [this version](https://github.com/sharekit/sharekit).